# Property attributes - strong vs copy example?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I understand that if an object property has a mutable subclass an attribute should be `copy` instead of `strong` in order to prevent the variable from mutating without the permission of the class. I created two different examples using `strong` just to fully understand the principle, but I do not understand the results of the second example.

```
@interface Person: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* siblings;

@end

@implementation Person

//init - initialize empty siblings array

//setter
- (void)setSiblings:(NSArray *)siblings{

     _siblings = siblings;

}

@end
```

**Example 1:**

```
int main{

    NSMutableArray* siblings = [@[@"Nikita"] mutableCopy];

    Person* person = [Person alloc] init];

    //This calls the setter and creates a strong
    //reference to the siblings array above
    person.siblings = siblings;

    NSLog(@"1: %@ ", person.siblings);

   //Here I am able to change the siblings array and that 
   //change will reflect inside the person.siblings instance variable
   [siblings addObject:@"Andre"];

   NSLog(@"2: %@ ", person.siblings);

}

Output: 
1: (Nikita) 
2: (Nikita, Andre)
```

**Example 2:**

```
int main{

    NSMutableArray* siblings = [@[@"Nikita"] mutableCopy];

    Person* person = [Person alloc] init];

    //This calls the setter and creates a strong
    //reference to the siblings array above
    person.siblings = siblings;

    NSLog(@"1: %@ ", person.siblings);

   //Here the change is not reflected in person.siblings instance variable
   siblings = [@[@"Andre"] mutableCopy];

   NSLog(@"2: %@ ", person.siblings);

}

Output:
1: (Nikita)
2: (Nikita)
```

Why is it that in the second example, when I change the value of `siblings` it is not changed in `person.siblings`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your second example:

```
siblings = [@[@"Andre"] mutableCopy];
```

You are changing the **local variable** named `siblings` to refer to a new object.  The `siblings` property of your `person` object still refers to the old array.

Here's what memory looks like before that line:

[image: before]

And here's what it looks like after:

[image: after]